# python: OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

Im trying to add data into mariadb tables. I want to pass the val0 to val5 as values of my query.
But i got error **OperationalError: near "%": syntax error**
Code

```
list_Values = ['dataName', '199', 0.1, 'A1', '2018-08-14']
val0 = list_Values[0]
val1 = int(list_Values[1])
val2 = list_Values[2]
val3 = list_Values[3]
val4 = list_Values[4]

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tab1 (Name, Number, Version, Grade, date_C) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s )", (val0, val1, val2, val3, val4))
```

Does anyone know how can i fix this error please?.

**Post Edited**

---

```
   OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-203-476c18b4c041> in <module>
  2 cursor.execute(" INSERT INTO tab1 (Name, Number, Version, Grade, 
  ----> 4 date_C) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s )", (val0, val1, val2, val3, val4))
  OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: @KlausD. post edited.. Pease have a look thank Youu

Comment: What SQL connector are you using, i.e. what do you `import`? Because for some connectors you need `?` rather than `%s` as placeholders, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python

Comment: import mysql.connector as mariadb @Błotosmętek

Comment: @Błotosmętek im using import mysql.connector as mariadb

Comment: Try replacing `(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s )` with `(?,?,?,?,?)` anyway.

Comment: @Błotosmętek got another error  **ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement**

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of ideas now.

Comment: Błotosmętek  https://answers.launchpad.net/myconnpy/+question/218821 In this link they said that the '?' is the source of the problem . And mariadb supports the only the "%s"

Comment: import mysql.connector as mariadb
mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='root', password='db1123', database='db1',host ='xxxxxxxx', port=3306)
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()

Answer (score 0):

I post my answer here hoping that can help persons that got my error. So try to use this **import**

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='xxx', password='xxxx', database='db1',host ='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', port=3306)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
list_Values = ['dataName', '199', 0.1, 'A1', '2018-08-14']
val0 = list_Values[0]
val1 = int(list_Values[1])
val2 = list_Values[2]
val3 = list_Values[3]
val4 = list_Values[4]

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tab1 (Name, Number, Version, Grade, date_C) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s )", (val0, val1, val2, val3, val4))
```